# I'm trying to have a flash embed as well as an iframe embed be on the same line

Tags: flash, iframe, embed

Alright, so I want to embed my Twitch.TV video feed as well as the chat embed side by side. Another thing I'm trying to do is make it so the video automatically re-sizes itself based on the browser resolution.

So, first off for the re-sizing issue, I've already changed the width='100%' which takes care of that, but from everything I've researched and tried implementing (min/max height, percentages, etc) none of it seems to work. Is it possible to have the height scale with the width (ie 1980 width = 1080 height, 16:9, 16:10, 4:3 based on browser)? If not, I think I might be fine having it at 400 height.

Onto my current issue. I've looked all around for this one. I've been able to research div, span, inline and it all works fine and well for text, but I can't get any of it to work with both embeds. Another thing to add, is that this is in a post on Joomla although I've taken out tinymce and the other editors to make sure the html and code isn't interrupted. I changed the username to a staff member.

```
<p>
  <object id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=thegunrun" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="400">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&amp;channel=thegunrun&amp;auto_play=true&amp;start_volume=25" />
  </object>
  <a class="trk" href="http://www.twitch.tv/thegunrun" style="padding: 2px 0px 4px; display: block; width: 345px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10px; text-decoration: underline; text-align: center;">Watch live video from TheGunRun's Channel on www.twitch.tv</a>
  <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=thegunrun&amp;popout_chat=true" height="500" width="350"></iframe>
</p>
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thanks for your time.

Thank you MikO for the code edit.

Comment: To resize properly you can use multiple .css files and load them by setting `media screen` option, there are some examples here http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1